# Using generating functions in Markov chains to find expected number of moves.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, generating-functions

Consider a sequence of 4 vaults labelled as E = {1, 2, 3, 4}. In vault 1 there is a policeman and in vault 4 there is a treasure chest. Vaults 2 and 3 are empty. Suppose there is a thief walking through the vaults and you can model the location of the thief, i.e. the corresponding vault number, at each point in time by a homogeneous Markov chain denoted by $(X_n)_{n∈{0,1,2,... }}$.
If the thief is in vault 1 (together with the policeman), he will run out of vault 1 to vault 2 with probability one. If the thief is in vault 4 (with the treasure), he will stay there forever. If the thief is in vault 2 or 3, he will either go left with probability 1/2 or he will go right with probability 1/2. Moreover, assume that the thief is not very clever, so he might return to vault 1 (with the policeman) several times. Also, suppose the policeman never manages to catch the thief and jail him (even if they are in the same vault).

Q) Suppose the thief starts his journey in vault 1. What is the expected number of moves required until the thief reaches the treasure chest? Justify your answer carefully.

I tried to solve this using the first hitting probability from vault 1 to 4:

$f_{14}(n)$ denotes the first hitting probability in n steps.
$P_{ij}(n)$ denotes the probability of going from state i to j in n steps
$f_{14}(n) = P_{13}(n-1)*1/2$ since we have to go from state 3
$P_{13}(n-1) = P_{12}(n-2)*1/2$ since we must have come from state 2

Then I attempted to find $P_{12}(n)$ which I said was equal to $(\frac{3}{4})^{(n-1)/2}$ since $P_{12}(n) = P_{12}(n-2) * 3/4$. (this may be a point of error but I believe this is correct).

Then $f_{14}(n) =  \frac{1}{4} * (\frac{3}{4})^{(n-3)/2}$

To find the expected time I used $d/ds(\sum(f_{14}s^n))$ and set s = 1 after differentiating. I do not however get the correct answer and I'm not sure if this is an error in the method or a calculation error. If it is an error in the method what is wrong?

Comment: I would just look at states.  There are only three active states, according to which vault (other than $\#4$) the thief is in.  Let $E_n$ denote the expected number of steps it will take from state $n$ and write down the obvious connections between the $E_n$.

Comment: Is there any reason to have a policeman in the problem? Why not simply work with the unknowns $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, where $x_k$ is denoting the expected number of steps to get from $k$ to $4$...?! Then $x_4=0$, and $x_1=1+x_2$, $x_2=1+\frac 12x_1+\frac 12x_3$, $x_3=1+\frac 12x_2+\frac 12x_4$ ...

Comment: This is just the question as taken from the problem sheet. That is how it is done in the answers however I was wanting to know where I had gone wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is an absorbing Markov chain, we can write the transition matrix
$$
P = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \begin{pmatrix}T &\mathbf T^0\\\mathbf 0^\intercal&1\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $T$ coresponds to transitions between transient states and $\mathbf T^0 + T\mathbf 1=\mathbf 1$. Here the initial distribution is $\mathbf \tau=(1,0,0)$, and so for $k=1,2,\ldots$ the probability that it takes the thief $k$ moves to reach the chest is given by
$$
f(k) = \mathbf \tau T^{k-1}\mathbf T^0 = \begin{cases}
\frac{3^{\frac {k-1}2-1}}{2^k},& k=3,5,7,9,\ldots\\
0,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
(with $T^0$ defined as the identity matrix). The expected number of steps to reach the vault is thus
$$
\sum_k k\cdot f(k) = \sum _{k=3}^{\infty } k\cdot \frac{3^{\frac {k-1}2-1}}{2^k} \left((-1)^k-1\right) = 9.
$$